# how to remove first letter if it's vowel and return no vowels if there is no vowel

Tags: python

Write the function startWithVowel(word) that takes in a word as argument and returns a substring that starts with the first vowel found in the word. The function returns 'No vowel' if the word does not contain vowel.

Examples

```
>>> startWithVowel('apple')
'apple'
>>> startWithVowel('google')
'oogle'
>>> startWithVowel('xyz')
'No vowel'
```

**My Answer**

```
def startWithVowel(word):
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        return word
    elif word[0] != 'aeiou' and word[1:] in 'aeiou':
        return word[1::]
    elif word not in 'aeiou':
        return "No vowel"
```

**MyQuestion**
I know how to remove first vowel letter if word contains any vowel, but i am stuck with this code.. using this logic it should return 'no vowel' for xyz. 
but it's returning 'yz' and i know where i am wrong, it's a logical problem in line 4. but i don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rather straightforward way to do it:

```
def startWithVowel(word):
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c.lower() in 'aeiou':
            return word[i:]
    return 'No vowel'

>>> for word in 'apple', 'google', 'xyz', 'BOGGLE':
...     print startWithVowel(word)
apple
oogle
No vowel
OGGLE
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this -

```
>>> def startWithVowel(word):
...     while len(word) > 0 and word[0] not in 'aeiou':
...             word = word[1:]
...     if len(word) == 0:
...             return 'No vowel'
...     return word
...
>>> startWithVowel('apple')
'apple'
>>> startWithVowel('google')
'oogle'
>>> startWithVowel('xyz')
'No vowel'
>>> startWithVowel('flight')
'ight'
```

Use `word[0].lower()` in the above loop, if you want to check case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your logic in line 4 is that you are using `!=` instead of `not in`. What you are doing is comparing word[0] which is a character and comparing it to the string `'aeiou'`. Naturally a single character will never be equal to a string. On top of that, `word[1:] in 'aeiou'` and `word in 'aeiou'` don't work. They are comparing strings, not iterating over each letter of the word and comparing the characters. You can fix this by doing the following

```
def startWithVowel(word):
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        return word
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(word)):
            if word[i] in 'aeiou': return word[i:]
        return "No vowel"
```

This says if the first letter is a vowel return the word, else, iterate over each letter in the word and look for a vowel. If a vowel is found then return the word from that index and if not then return 'No vowel'

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re.search`.

```
import re
def findstring(s):
    m = re.search(r'(?i)[aeiou].*', s)
    if m:
        return m.group()
    else:
        return "No vowel"
```

Comment: `NameError: global name 're' is not defined` :) Also, the function should return the string, not print it.

Comment: `import re` to tackle `NameError: global name 're' is not defined`

Comment: @SparkandShine: I know that, you know that, Avinash knows that. But the OP might not. And it really ought to be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Why you people hate regex and love the for loop answer? It's about performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
def startWithVowel(word):
dataLen=len(word)
newStr=''
if word[0] in 'aieou':
   return word
for xx in range(1,dataLen):
     count=0
     if word[0] not in 'aieou' and word[xx] in "aieou" or word[xx] not in 'aieou':
        newStr=newStr+word[xx]
        if(word[xx] in 'aieou'):
           count=count+1
if count>0:
   return newStr
else:
    return 'No vowel'          
#return newStr
for xx in word:
    if xx not in 'aieou':
       return 'No vowel'
```

Comment: you should not just put code in an answer, better describe what you have done and why this is a solution.